# Django Template Engine is wrongly concataining urls

Tags: python, django

In a django template when I create a link with an href, the url of the current page is put before the link I want to indicate.
So, 
let's say I am on [register]. From there I want to go to [connected] and I do a template rendering with a [] but in fact the django template create a wrong [href=register/connected]. How is that possible ??

For info, my url.py :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
url(r'^logout'          , 'database.views.logout_view', name='logout_view'),    
url(r'^login'           , 'database.views.index', name='login'),
url(r'^create-user'     ,  'database.views.account_creation', name='create_user'),

url(r'^browse-contacts'     ,  'database.views.browse_contacts', name='browse_contacts'),

url(r'^get-details'     ,  'database.views.get_details', name='get-details'),
url(r'^upload-csv'  ,  'database.views.upload_csv', name='upload_csv'),
url(r'^mail'  ,  'database.views.testsendmail'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin', include(admin.site.urls)),

url(r'^register/$', 'database.views.register'),
url(r'^activate/(?P<key>.+)$', 'database.views.activation'),
url(r'^new-activation-link/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', 'database.views.new_activation_link'),
#url(r'^'           , 'database.views.index', name='login'),
#url(r'^.*', 'database.views.index', name='unmatched')
```

)

and an example of template :

```
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/get-details">Set my details</a></li>
        <li><a href="/upload-csv/">Upload a csv of contacts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout/">     Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
    {{ message }}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

So, trying to access :

```
http://issc.romain.webfactional.com/browse-contacts
```

I got redirect to :

```
 http://issc.romain.webfactional.com/accounts/login/?next=/browse-contacts
```

which give me an error :

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://issc.romain.webfactional.com/accounts/login/?next=/browse-contacts
Using the URLconf defined in issc.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^logout [name='logout_view']
^login [name='login']
^create-user [name='create_user']
^browse-contacts [name='browse_contacts']
^get-details [name='get-details']
^upload-csv [name='upload_csv']
^mail
^admin
^register/$
^activate/(?P<key>.+)$
^new-activation-link/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
```

As you have the website name you can try yourself ;)

And here is the brows_contacts function :

```
@login_required

def browse_contacts(request  ):
    begin       = int(request.GET.get('begin', 0))
    go_ahead    = True
    limit       = 2
previous    = max(0, begin-limit)
ending      = begin + limit
to_display  = {}

users_      = User.objects.all().order_by('-last_login')[begin:ending]
from pprint import pprint
for u in users_:
    to_display[u] = {"id" : u.id}
    for infos in u.field_set.all() :
        if infos.name.encode("utf-8") != "id":
            to_display[u][infos.name.encode("utf-8")] = infos.value.encode("utf-8")

    for infos in u.userinfo_set.all() :
        for k,v in infos.__dict__.items():
            if k[0].strip() != "_" and k.strip().encode("utf-8") != "id":
                to_display[u][str(k).encode("utf-8")] = str(v).encode("utf-8")



if(len(users_)<limit):
    go_ahead = False

context = {"to_display" : to_display , "go_ahead": go_ahead, "next" : ending , "previous" : previous}           
return render(request, "browse-contacts.html", context)
```

Comment: can you show your urls.py and fragment of template where this happened? Also some information about environment (http server etc) would be appreciated.

Comment: You're probably using relative URLs (ie without an initial slash). But you shouldn't be hard-coding URLs anyway, you should be using the `{% url %}` tag.

Comment: The produced href are like this on the html =>  [ this : <a href="/get-details">Set my details</a> ] but when clicked it goes to [url= www.website.com/accounts/login/?next=/get-details ]

Comment: It's sending you to `accounts/login` because you've indicated that your `browse_contacts` view requires a login by using the `@login_required` decorator. The default URL for that decorator is `accounts/login`. You can change that by either changing the `LOGIN_URL` setting in your `settings.py` file, or you can pass a parameter to the `@login_required` decorator. It looks like `@login_required('/login')` will work for your setup.